# How to configure and use KeyExpirationEventMessageListener with Redis Repositories?

Tags: spring-data-redis

Our application needs to listen to Redis key expired events and process the data in the key. Using RedisMessageListenerContainer I can get the expiry events but those only contain the expired key and not the key value. Hence wanted to use KeyExpirationEventMessageListener along with Redis Repository.

But am not able to configure KeyExpirationEventMessageListener and wanted some guidance for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is register an `ApplicationListener` for eg. `RedisKeyExpiredEvent`.

```java
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)
public class Config {

    @Bean
    ApplicationListener<RedisKeyExpiredEvent<Person>> eventListener() {
        return event -> {
            System.out.println(String.format("Received expire event for key=%s with value %s.",
                    new String(event.getSource()), event.getValue()));
        };
    }
}
```

You can find a full sample [here](https://github.com/christophstrobl/next-level-redis-with-spring/blob/master/src/test/java/org/example/repository/RepsoitoryTests.java#L183).

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I am getting exception saying CONFIG GET is not enabled when using EnableKeySpaceEvents option. It seems to be disabled in PCF redis service. I have enabled keyspace events through Redis config for the service and I can listen to them using a listener container but not using a repository.... is there an option to ovverride the get config?

Comment: The problem was with the managed Redis instance in our managed cloud instance, where the set config command was disabled, and hence the enabling of the keyspace events was not working.

Answer (score 0):

#### @EventListener approach

I've done this in a bit different way, using Spring's `@EventListener`.

```java
@Slf4j
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)
@Configuration
public class RedisListenerConfig {

    @EventListener
    public void handleRedisKeyExpiredEvent(RedisKeyExpiredEvent<String> event) {
        String eventId = new String(event.getId());
        log.info("Key {} has expired. Value {}", eventId, event.getValue());
    }

}
```

The whole manual can be found here [Baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-ttl)

Working on Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.x.x as well as on Java 8 and Spring Boot 2.5.x